# How to get sub arrays(like reducing first 1000 rows) of a string 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a huge 2D string array. I want to read first 1000 rows from the 2D array and copy the elements into few other 2D arrays and reduce the original array by 1000 rows to save memory. I have tried something like below code:

```
    public static String[][] getSubArray(String[][] origArray, int offset) {
        String[][] tempArray = new String[origArray.length - offset][];
        System.arraycopy(origArray, offset, tempArray, 0, tempArray.length);
        return tempArray;
    }
```

but this doesn't work as expected and I get wrong arrays.

Comment: Could you give an example of the `String[][] origArray`?

Comment: You can't reduce the array size, you have to copy the data to a smaller array.

Answer (score 2):

First point, it that array in `Java` is an `Object`. When you init new array (i.e. `String[][] arr = new String[10_000][10_000]`) it means, that you have continuous area in memory to hold all `10_000 x 10_000` string elements, and reference `arr` to this `Object`. It is not possible to reduce size of array. E.g. `ArrayList` increase internal array size by creating new Object and rewrite reference `arr`.

So, you want to get 1000 elements from the array and reduce existed array to save memory. By the steps it means:

1. Create new 2D array 1 to save 1000 elements;
2. Copy 1000 elements from original array into new array 1;
3. Create new 2D array 2 to save rest elements of original array;
4. Copy rest element into new array 2;
5. Change reference `arr` to array 2.

Original array will be available for GC, but it is still exists (because GC could never be started). In any case, as result of what you think to do, will be *increase* memory usage.

I offer to avoid all this array copy. E.g. you have huge 2D array. Do not modify this array. Let it be in memory as one array. You have all data you need. Just add offset to your methods, and let them ready data from the original array.

Moreover, 2D array in `Java` is an *array of arrays*. This mean, that you can get a reference to the required row without copying it to the new array. Example:

```
String[][] originalArray = new String[2][2];
String[] row_0 = originalArray[0];
String[] row_1 = originalArray[1];
```

**P.S.** Of course, in case you have to send this array within REST or out of current JVM, then you definetly have to create a copy of required part, but still you do not have to change original array.

**Example:**

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    String[][] origArray = {
            { "1.1", "1.2", "1.3", "1.4", "1.5" },
            { "2.1", "2.2", "2.3", "2.4", "2.5" },
            { "3.1", "3.2", "3.3", "3.4", "3.5" },
            { "4.1", "4.2", "4.3", "4.4", "4.5" },
            { "5.1", "5.2", "5.3", "5.4", "5.5" } };

    int offs = 0;
    final int rows = 2;

    while (offs < origArray.length) {
        doSomething(origArray, offs, rows);
        offs += rows;
        System.out.println("---");
    }

    originalArray = null;  // make it available for GC
}

public static void doSomething(String[][] origArray, int offs, int rows) {
    for (int row = offs; row < origArray.length && row < offs + rows; row++)
        doSomethingWithArray(origArray[row], row);
}

public static void doSomethingWithArray(String[] arr, int row) {
    // here you have a reference to row from originalArray (without copying it to the new array) 
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

*Output:*

```
[1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5]
[2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5]
---
[3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5]
[4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4, 4.5]
---
[5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5]
---
```

As you can see, I `doSomething` with 3 iterations by 2 rows. And do not have any array copy or smth like that.

**P.S.** After all, do not forget to clear all references to you huge array, to make it available for GC.

Comment: I need to copy elements from origArray to few different 2D arrays so its already duplication of the elements. What I really want is to copy first few rows to the other 2D arrays. According to your solution, I will be reading few rows at a time form original array and copying them to other arrays, this will certainly reduce sudden rise of memory usage but is there a way I can free up the memory taken up by the already copied elements?